# Bootstrap navbar customization without losing functionality

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm converting an existing site to responsive and I've gotten to the navigation bar.  On the old site has a very simple navigation bar with some  styling on it.  Just a `<ul>` with `<li>` for each item and a nested `<ul>` for a dropdown. It looks like this:  [image]

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Entire fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t3haykzd/

I want to make a responsive navbar that looks exactly like this if possible. From what I understand it is bad practice to edit the bootstrap source directly.  Looking at bootstraps navbar, I notice it has 2 elements, the `header` and then the menu itself which is an unordered list.

Is there a simple way to incorporate my current style into this navbar while making sure it's responsive?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar) section of bootstrap? You also can play with bootstrap stylings by using your own css file, loaded *after* bootstrap's, that uses common class / id / element conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that should get you started. The important thing to keep in mind (at least with this example) is the use of media queries to build the navigation in a fashion similar to your current one so you don't disturb the mobile functionality @ under 768px. The vast majority is simple styling.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #2A92C2;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #002B5C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2A92C2;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background-color: #2A92C2;
  color: #FFF;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:hover {
  background-color: #2A92C2;
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
/*Distribute Links*/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default > .container-fluid {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
/*Mobile Brand*/

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    color: #2A92C2;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    <p>Sup</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow beautiful answer! Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following link to do this might be helpful to you.

- http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/
- http://bootstrapdesigntools.com/tools/bootstrap-menu-builder/
- http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/07/less-like-bootstrap/

This one is bootstrap own to customize the bootstrap components look and feel.

- http://getbootstrap.com/customize/